# Django: The requested URL /accounts/login/ was not found on this server

Tags: python, django, apache, url

What part of this view is making me access this url and why can it not be accessed? I have never seen it before. Everything was fine on my development machine and now I've moved it to production on an Apache server and I can't figure out how to solve this error.

```
def new_user(request):
    form = NewAccountForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']

        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        except:
            return HttpResponse("That username is already taken. Please try a different one.")

        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.save()

        if bool(request.FILES.get('picture', False)):
            pic = request.FILES.get('picture')
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
            profile.picture = pic
            profile.save()
        else:
            user.delete()
            return HttpResponse("Please upload a profile picture.")

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')

    else:
        return HttpResponse("The form you submitted was invalid. Please enter appropriate input.")
```

The form action that triggers this view is:

```
<form action="app/new_user/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I think it is the `login` function but could anybody provide any more insight?

Comment: It might be `'home'` url if it requires authenticated user. Check user is properly created and `authenticate` returns valid user.

Comment: I've got the same problem! And moreover it seems to be random! I've made a Unity application, if I try to get my "own" login view with `@method_decorator(login_required)` then, sometimes, it redirects to the right view = `/accounts/login/?next=/en/j/login` and sometimes it doesn't find that view and I get the message `Not Found: /accounts/login/`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I'm using class views, but I guess you may have a problem like mine.
The problem came from the fact that I was mixing `login_required` and `ensure_csrf_cookie` directives, like this:

```
class JsonBase(generic.View):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({}, safe=False)
```

So I thought: if the user is not connected, for the `get` method, never mind it's ok, I just return an empty Json object, and in my descendant classes, I'll do the comparison if I need to `if request.user.is_authenticated: [blabla]`.

So here's my final working "base" Json view:

```
class JsonBase(generic.View):

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({}, safe=False)

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({}, safe=False)
```